# Best way to transfer data contract from service to consumer

Tags: c#, json, wcf, web-services, rest

What is the standard or best way to transfer a data contract from a JSON RESTful web service to a consuming application? With XML, there is the xsd.exe that can take XML -> XSD -> C#. I am looking for something along those lines or something that the web service could run on their data contracts and send to the consuming application.

Ive searched through a lot of the stack overflow questions but most dont answer or are outdated (2-3 years old).

Answer (score 0):

Use a framework such as [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) that handles serialization between your .NET and JSON based objects.

Comment: I meant that I want to be able to send something so a consumer can create their data contracts automagically. Similar to sending a .xsd file for an XML service. This looks like it just serializes and deserializes

Comment: it's javascript, which is not a strongly typed language, so there is no concept of a contract, and can't enforce contracts like c#/soap based services can. when you receive a json object back from RESTful service, it will be similar to your .net objects, with the same properties.